# How to connect to Oracle from Python running on IBM i?

Tags: python, oracle, ibm-midrange

There is a requirement in my project to install python on the IBM I series server. Though we have good documentation on the installation, but very less on the database drivers needed to connect from the I series to Oracle. Iam assuming I might have to use JDBC thin drivers for python to connect to Oracle, as its recommended to use JDBC drivers to connect from RPG.

I tested a python code using Jaydebeapi module and it works fine from locally(windows), but Iam not sure if it will work from the I series server. Also please correct me if Iam wrong that PYODBC needs a client software to work and may not be a good choice in this case ?.

Comment: requirement here is to connect to a Oracle database.

Comment: I don't want to post an answer because I have not actually done it myself, but I suspect you will indeed have to use JDBC. You should try it out yourself. JPype (as `jpype1`) and JayDeBeApi both seem to install successfully on IBM i (in PASE) using pip3. You could also try [py4jdbc](https://pypi.org/project/py4jdbc/) and [Py4J](https://www.py4j.org/).

Comment: Thanks John, I am working with my I series admin and will post the outcome once we finish installing and executing a script.

Comment: with the JPype when i run the code i get the terminate called after throwing an instance of 'JPypeException' error

Comment: anyone has experience starting JVM on AIX ?, iam currently stuck with a JVM crash on AIX after it start, Iam attempting to start it from JPYPE package. Are there any tools to tell if any shared libraries are missing ?